# Azure DevOps Roll back after promoting build to production

Tags: azure-devops

We are using trunk based development and we have dev sandbox and production environments in Azure DevOps. We move build from dev to sandbox to production by promoting the builds. After moving build to production if there is an issue is there anything the pipeline i can define to trigger a rollback.

The only other option I can think of is get the last know commit number and trigger a build with that commit number. and let the pipeline take care of the rest. Is this correct is there a better way to do rollback in AzureDevops

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Each release is a snapshot of the deployed artifact(s) and variables. The simplest "rollback" is simply to go to the Release Management history for the project, locate the previous release, and deploy it again to replace the newer release. Complications can arise if there are, for example, incompatible database changes.